# Error 'nuitka' is a package and cannot be directly executed when trying to execute Nuitka

Tags: python, nuitka

I have two python installations on Windows (3.4 and 3.5) where py refers to 3.4.

I installed nuitka using their 3.4 64 bit installer and then I installed Python 2.7 because it was listed as a requirement.

Then I tried:

```
> py -m nuitka
```

And got the error:

```
C:\Python34\python.exe: No module named nuitka.__main__; 'nuitka' is a package and cannot be directly executed
```

Comment: What makes you think that's how you call it?

Comment: Because I tried to call it with nuitka and it didn't work. And the documentation says nothing further on command line usage which I presume is the simplest part

Comment: So I take it you have nothing else to say...

Comment: You're talking to the whole internet, not just me.

Comment: I've posted a question about [using `py` to select an installed binary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34968708/using-python-launcher-for-windows-to-select-a-binary-in-the-scripts-directory). You can probably get it to work by calling `py -3.4 C:\Python34\Scripts\nuitka.py` but it would be nice to not have the duplicated version in the command.

Comment: I was talking to the guy that deleted the answer on which we had a long back and forth about the problem. Thanks for making that question. I do not have a `nuitka.py` in my scritpts folder. All I can see are two nuitka and nuitka-run files, one with no file extension and one as a .bat

Comment: Try `C:\Python34\Scripts\nuitka.bat` then.

Comment: Trying to do `py -3.4 C:\...` gives `nuitka.bat: line 1 @echo off SyntaxError: invalid syntax`. If I try to do `py -3.4 -m ...` it gives the error: `Error while finding spec for 'C:\\Python34\\Scripts\\nui
tka.bat' (<class 'ImportError'>: No module named 'C:\\Python34\\Scripts\\nuitka'
)`

Comment: Sorry, I meant just the `bat`, not using `py` at all.

Comment: It worked! It threw a few errors saying I should only be using it as a python module or part of the main program but it is now functional. Please post it as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nuitka can be accessed through its batch file in Python's script folder. For example:

```
"C:\Python34\Scripts\nuitka.bat" --version
> 0.5.18
```