# Using Python launcher for Windows to select a binary in the Scripts directory

Tags: python, python-3.x

[Python launcher for Windows](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#python-launcher-for-windows) can find Python installations and select a particular version of the interpreter to run:

```
c:/>py -3.4
```

Is it possible to select some other binary from the installation?

For example `nose`, `behave`, `nuitka`, and many others install a script or binary which can be run directly, if the `Script` directory in on the `path`. e.g:

```
c:/behave
```

Can `py` be used to select which `behave` to call?

I know I can instead select a whole `virtualenv`, but I was wondering whether `py` has more uses than selecting the interpreter binary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've wondered this too, but PEP 397 says that it's for choosing the right python executable, and doesn't mention anything about any binaries that may be included with installed packages in the python path.

https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0397/

The only way I've solved this is through virtual environments, like you mentioned.